# How does the bonus system work in Uncharted 3?

Tags: ps3, uncharted-3

Does Uncharted 3 simply not have a bonus menu like UC2, or do you have to do beat it on crushing to fully unlock it?

Maybe I misremember things, but it seemed like UC2 had a menu system with lists of trophies won, weapons that could be equipped, and various skins, mirror modes, etc. Initially most of these were locked, but you could see that they existed; even before completing on crushing. I just don't see anything in the main menu system of UC3 that leads to that information. All I can find is player statistics, and the list of treasures found.

Does UC3 just not have that menu system? If that's the case, how do you even know which trophies you have and don't have?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, unfortunately Uncharted 3 does not feature the same kind of unlock system that Uncharted 2 did, or any other single-player unlock/cheat system.

There are still plenty of (in fact, a lot more) unlocks for multiplayer games, including skins, guns, attachments, boosters, etc.

I'd cite a source, but guides that don't mention an unlockables menu that doesn't exist isn't very helpful. GameFAQs, which is *usually* fairly reliable, has [this page](http://www.gamefaqs.com/ps3/615426-uncharted-3-drakes-deception/cheats) for cheats and unlockables. Nothing on guns or single-player.

As for trophies - how do you check for any other game? Using the PS3 Trophies menu. There aren't separate PS3 Trophies/Uncharted medals in this one, it's just the Trophy list.

**Edit** 
- just a few other questions on other websites, all saying the same thing. Nothing concrete, just additional info:

- [Gamespot forum thread](http://www.gamespot.com/uncharted-3-drakes-deception/answers/where-can-i-find-the-post-game-bonuses-298484)
- [IGN forum thread](http://boards.ign.com/uncharted_drakes_fortune/b11422/206506304/p1/)

Comment: So there's just not an option to equip with the Wes44 and the SAS12 (or whatever) and go back and exact some righteous revenge in your favorite shoot-outs? Bummer. But I guess there are too many chapters that are scripted to start off weaponless to be compatible with such a feature.

Comment: @JustJeff nope, I'm afraid not. I was rather upset at this omission too!

Comment: @JustJeff don't forget to upvote/accept if appropriate ;)

Comment: of course. I just like to let my questions ride for at least a couple of hours before throwing an accept.

Comment: I think they will come as DLC or as an update. It really bummed me out knowing they weren't there. Cross your fingers and hope they come!